# ¿Cómo puedo extraer info como una List<> en java desde un rest template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, microservices

Estoy intentando obtener info de una llamada rest así:

```
rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8091/registros/" + userId, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Registro>>(){});
```

Pero me dice que los tipos en rest template no son aplicables. ¿Algún tip sobre como extraer una lista con rest?

Comment: Tal vez sea porque `List` es una interfaz, y necesitas una clase con implementación como por ejemplo un `ArrayList`? Quiero decir, quieres que te devuelva una Lista, pero no le indicas ***qué*** tipo de lista...

Comment: intenté esto

  List<Registro> registros = Arrays.asList(
    rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8091/registros/" + userId, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayList<Registro>>() {})
    );

Y me sigue dando error... el mismo error.

Comment: Hola @ClaudioRowe la limitante que tienes es porque no puedes utilizar `ParameterizedTypeReference` con el método `getForObject`,  si verificas `getForObject` no tiene un constructor que permita `ParameterizedTypeReference` a diferencia de el método `exchange`, te dejo algunas soluciones como respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes aquí es porque el método `getForObject` no permite utilizar la clase `ParameterizedTypeReference`, a continuación te detallo 2 soluciones:

Solución 1: Utilizar `exchange` que si permite utilizar `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

```
    ResponseEntity<List<Registro>> respuesta = rt.exchange("http://localhost:8091/registros/" + userId,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Registro>>() { });

    List<Registro> registros = respuesta.getBody();
```

Solución 2: Utilizar un objeto envoltorio para la lista `RegistroLista`  con el método `getForObject`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RegistroLista {
    private List<Registro> resgitros;

    public RegistroLista() {
        resgitros = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Registro> getResgitros() {
        return resgitros;
    }

    public void setResgitros(List<Registro> resgitros) {
        this.resgitros = resgitros;
    }
}
```

---

```
    RegistroLista repuesta = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8091/registros/" + userId, RegistroLista.class);

    List<Registro> registros = repuesta.getResgitros();
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: @ClaudioRowe espero y te haya servido la información, recuerda que si esta o otra repuesta soluciono tu problema marcar la como solución para que la comunidad de SO pueda saber que encontraste la solución.

Comment: hecho! muchas gracias